# What is the maximum range of an ICBM in Voltz?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-voltz

I'd like to know what the maximum possible range is for any ICBM in the Voltz modpack for Minecraft.

Thanks

EDIT: Seems to be about 200 blocks, but I don't know if this is extendable somehow or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some experimenting and Tier 1 missiles seem to have a 200 block range. Tier 3 missiles have a much much farther range (600+ blocks).

Answer (score 2):

There is now somewhat more information available on the [ICBM mod wiki](http://wiki.universalelectricity.com/icbm). In particular:

> Missiles have a default range of 2000 blocks (configurable in the mod config). They will load chunks as they pass through them.

The chunkloading behaviour as missiles fly is a new feature, so the 2km default range is probably also new.